# Invalid token - invalid request BLR at offset 340 function F_LRTRIM is not defined

Tags: firebird, user-defined-functions

I am trying to synchronize two Firebird databases with each other. First of all, I already configured that the synchronization will be one-way. Therefore, one database is the Source-DB and the other is the target-DB.

To start a synchronization I use IBReplicator! When I start the synchronization, I get the error:

```
Exception: Invalid token
invalid request BLR at offset 340
function F_LRTRIM is not defined 
module name or entrypoint could not be found
```

I started searching for the cause of the problem. What I already checked:

- .dll files exist in the firebird directory
- Firebird version is 32 - bit
- IBExpert displays the UDF in the UDF Section of the database.

I read that it could be a problem when there is a mismatch between Firebird Server version and .dll file version. But I don't know how to verify the versions.

And I wanted to search for a .conf file to check the path for the UDF file (.dll) but I didn't find it. I only found the firebird.conf file and I already set the UDFAccess to Full.

I would really appreciate if someone could help me. I wasted a huge amount of time in this problem.

Comment: Using setting `UdfAccess` to `Full` is insecure. In any case, the error suggests that you don't have the right UDF libraries, or Firebird can't find it (meaning the configuration is incorrect or the location of the library is not on the path). The fact the UDF is defined in the database means nothing: it may be defined, but at runtime, Firebird can't find the required library. With the information provided we can't really help you. Also, consider switching to [`TRIM`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-intfunc-trim.html).

Comment: Possibly changing `UdfAccess` to `Restrict <location of the UDF>` might solve your problem.

Comment: I‘ll write {Restrict C:\Program Files (x86)\Firebird\Firebird_2_5\UDF}

Comment: Or should I add the file + extension at the end of the String?

Comment: In that case you can use `Restrict UDF` (which is the default anyway).

Comment: It's worked out! Thank you, the error disappeared and I can continue with my work!

Comment: for future cases like `•.dll files exist in the firebird directory` - learn SysInternals Process Monitor tool - it could have show you if FB server even tried to find the DLL, and if it did - in which folders did it tried. Then you could deduce what kind of settings are blocking FB and need to be made relaxed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that Firebird can't find the entrypoint or library when the function is executed. This means that

1. The library can't be found: it is not on the (library) path or in one of the folders listed in the `UdfAccess` configuration
2. The library was found, but it is 32 bit and you're running 64 bit (or it's 64 bit and you're running 32 bit)
3. The library was found, but doesn't have the entrypoint for the UDF.

Your problem seems to be the first, and the solution is to add the location of the UDF to the `UdfAccess` configuration. Given the comments, you should use

```
UdfAccess = Restrict UDF
```

Which will only allow UDF libraries from the `UDF` directory of your Firebird installation. If needed you can list multiple directories separated by `;`.

You should never use `UdfAccess = Full`, it is unsafe as it can possibly be used to compromise your system with any library on the (library) path of your system.