# BLR error when connecting to Firebird database

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

I want connect Firebird databases on my local folder via FlameRobin. I can connect to all databases except one. I get this error for this db:

> invalid request BLR at offset 2801 function GETUSERINFO is not defined
>   module name or entrypoint could not be found.

[image: Error]

I couldn't find any resources for this error. Is this error caused by the database version difference?

Comment: _"Is this error caused by the database version difference?"_ What database version difference? Have you left out important information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error means that your database has an [on connect trigger](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-ddl-trgr-dbtrigger) that uses a UDF (user defined function), and it can't find the library (Windows: `.dll`, Linux: `.so`) with the code of that UDF.

You will need to find out which library this database needs, and install that in the proper location (default is the `udf` directory in the Firebird installation, but this can be changed in the `firebird.conf` setting `UdfAccess`).

An alternative cause of this error is using Firebird 64 bit, while the library is 32 bit (or vice versa). You will need to ensure both Firebird and the library are the same bitness.

Alternatively, you could connect to the database as SYSDBA, passing the `isc_dpb_no_db_triggers` connection property to disable the database triggers for that connection. I'm not sure if you can do that with FlameRobin.

See also [Invalid token - invalid request BLR at offset 340 function F_LRTRIM is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52056878/invalid-token-invalid-request-blr-at-offset-340-function-f-lrtrim-is-not-defin)

Answer (score 0):

To add, while it may not be the problem experienced by the poster, I had a similar issue when connecting to a remote server. When connecting to a remote server, the syntax looks like:

```
>gsec -user SYSDBA -password masterke -database <Server>/<Port>:<FDB>
```

where I erroneously specified the <*FDB*> as the name of my database, similar to what is done when using ISQL. This results in the following error:

```
GSEC> display
invalid request BLR at offset 37
table USERS is not defined
```

However by simply specifying the Security2.fdb then there is no problem:

```
>gsec -user SYSDBA -password masterke -database <Server>/<Port>:Security2.fdb
```

Note that when running gsec on the server itself, only the credentials need to be used - no '`-database`' option is required.